# Best Rails HTML Parser

Tags: html, ruby, parsing

I know that Hpricot is still a standard but I remember hearing about a faster more expressive HTML parser for Ruby.

Does anybody know what it's called and if it is worth switching to from Hpricot??

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/html_parsing.html. I also want to add LibXML is fast but cannot handle standard web wild HTML.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are probably thinking about [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/).
I have not used it myself, but "everyone" is talking about it and the [benchmarks](http://gist.github.com/24605) do look interesting:

```
hpricot:html:doc  48.930000 3.640000 52.570000 ( 52.900035)
hpricot2:html:doc  4.500000 0.020000  4.520000 (  4.518984)
nokogiri:html:doc  3.640000 0.130000  3.770000 (  3.770642)
```

Comment: The other nice thing about Nokogiri is that is was built with Hpricot in mind, so the syntax is almost identical.  So switching shouldn't be a big deal at all for you.

Answer (score 5):

There are multiple tools available. I use [**Nokogiri**](http://nokogiri.org/).

Demo:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(%{
  <h1 class="title">Hello, World</h1>
  <p>Some text</p>
  <a href="http://www.google.com/">Some link</a>
})

title   = doc.at_css("h1.title").text
content = doc.at_css("p").text
url     = doc.at_css("a")[:href]
```

Ryan Bates made an excelent screencast about using it: [#190: **Screen Scraping with Nokogiri**](http://railscasts.com/episodes/190-screen-scraping-with-nokogiri).

**Documentation**: http://nokogiri.org/

**Tutorials**: http://nokogiri.org/tutorials

Answer (score 2):

There is also [Rubyful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/RubyfulSoup/)

Which sells itself as a lightweight quick and dirty parser.  I found the interface very intuitive and 'Ruby-ish' when using it for a project in the past, which is perhaps a little surprising given that it is a Python port.

Edit: looks like it's no longer maintained unfortunately so it's probably not the one you were looking for.  Looks like Nokogiri is the on you've been hearing about.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use regular expressions -- ruby's regex stuff is way too slow.  Hpricot is awesome and Nokogiri looks promising, though I've not used it directly yet.