# Loading a webpage for parsing in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parsing, html-parsing

Assume, I want to get a page from the web to my application and make some sort of parsing with it. How do I do that? Where should I start from? Should be some plugins/gems required? What is your usual practice in resolving such type of tasks?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should try Gems like [Hpricot](http://github.com/whymirror/hpricot/tree/master) ([wiki](http://wiki.github.com/whymirror/hpricot/hpricot-basics)) or [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.rubyforge.org/nokogiri/).

Hpricot example:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'rubygems'
require 'hpricot'

html = Hpricot(open(an_url).read)
# This would search for any images inside a paragraph (XPath)
html.search('/html/body//p//img')
# This would search for any images with the class "test" (CSS selector)
html.search('img.test')
```

Nokogiri example:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'rubygems'
require 'hpricot'

html = Nokogiri::HTML(open(an_url).read)
# This would search for any images inside a paragraph (XPath)
html.xpath('/html/body//p//img')
# This would search for any images with the class "test" (CSS selector)
html.css('img.test')
```

Nokogiri is generally faster. Both libraries feature a lot of functionality.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is called "***Scraping***"

Ryan Bates made two excelent screencasts on this topic:

- [#190: Screen Scraping with Nokogiri](http://railscasts.com/episodes/190-screen-scraping-with-nokogiri)
- [#173 Screen Scraping with ScrAPI](http://railscasts.com/episodes/173-screen-scraping-with-scrapi)

I personally like Nokogiri more. You can also check out the following answer: [Best Rails HTML Parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/395261/best-rails-html-parser/9177693)